# Python, созать временный json файл

Tags: python

Есть процесс python, в какой то момент он вызывает другой процесс python, который в свою очередь генерирует данные, простой словарь по сути. Не перегружая вопрос лишними подробностями просто скажу, что напрямую нельзя передать этот словарь в первый процесс чем то типа:

```
#FIRST PROCESS:
import SecondProcessDictGenerationClass

dict_from_2nd_process = SecondProcessDictGenerationClass.get_my_dict(some_params_from_first_process)
```

Более того, сокетом тоже нельзя (по разным причинам, очень долго описывать, но точно нельзя).
Пришла идея через временные файлы действовать. Насколько я понимаю, можно создать какой то временный json, который будет существовать очень короткое время где то в системе, который я могу создать и заполнить своим словарем в первом процессе таким образом, что бы изначально как то "определять ссылку на него" из первого процесса, и в рамках первого процесса после завершения второго я могу использовать эту ссылку для открытия, чтения и удаления данного json?

Я никогда со временными файлами не работал, поэтому возможно я не правильно понимаю механику. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать? Возможно есть иные способы обмена данными между процессами, буду благодарен если подскажите.

Comment: В случае с временными файлами: создаёте файл, загружаете туда список, читаете файл из первого процесса и удаляете его. В целом всё, временные файлы - точно такие же, как и не временные, только удаляются после использования)

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы создать json-файл, введите сперва следующее:

```
import json
OUT_FILENAME = 'out.json'
```

А затем в конце, когда извлекаете что-то в JSON:

```
with open(OUT_FILENAME, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=1)
```

Надеюсь, чем-то помог? Это всё, что знаю. Я сам в какой-то степени пока ещё начинающий.

На всякий случай вот определения, что такое 'w' в with open

```
 ''r''   Open text file for reading.  The stream is positioned at the
         beginning of the file.

 ''r+''  Open for reading and writing.  The stream is positioned at the
         beginning of the file.

 ''w''   Truncate file to zero length or create text file for writing.
         The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

 ''w+''  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not
         exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is positioned at
         the beginning of the file.

 ''a''   Open for writing.  The file is created if it does not exist.  The
         stream is positioned at the end of the file.  Subsequent writes
         to the file will always end up at the then current end of file,
         irrespective of any intervening fseek(3) or similar.

 ''a+''  Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not
         exist.  The stream is positioned at the end of the file.  Subse-
         quent writes to the file will always end up at the then current
         end of file, irrespective of any intervening fseek(3) or similar.
```

Comment: В вопросе там что-то ещё про два процесса было и про обмен между ними )